# Is it still possible to find Braun Lectron System around, or equivalent?

Tags: analog

Is it still possible to find Braun Lectron System or equivalent around ?

For those who don't know about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raytheon_Lectron.

It is basically analog building blocks that did not need any wire to connect (instead the interconnects were made with other blocks with same dimensions).

Comment: Heh, nowadays they are digital, and called FPGAs :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Braun Lectron System is pretty clever.

You might also be interested in other similar systems for quickly prototyping electronic circuits using quick-connect modules:

- littleBits "electronics components attached with magnets" http://littlebits.cc/
- B-Squares uses magnetic contacts http://www.b-squares.com/
- Snap Circuits http://www.snapcircuits.net/
- the JeeNode and compatible "plugs" http://jeelabs.com/collections/all
- LilyTiny, LilyPad, and acessories http://hlt.media.mit.edu/?p=2198 http://web.media.mit.edu/~leah/LilyPad/ https://www.sparkfun.com/categories/135?
- the Arduino and compatible "shields" http://shieldlist.org/
- PlugaPods http://www.newmicros.com/
- Bug Labs modules http://www.buglabs.net/products
- Electronic Brick http://imall.iteadstudio.com/prototyping/electronic-brick.html?limit=25
- FlexStack http://www.boston-engineering.com/flexstack
- E-Blocks http://contest.techbriefs.com/component/content/article/1835
- Various other stacking modular connector boards http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Robotics/Computer_Control/The_Interface/SBC_and_multichip_modules#Stacking_modular_connector_boards

Answer (score 3):

I bought mine about a year ago at eBay. As there were some parts missing, I was happy to find a small company in Germany which is still producing Braun Lectron:

< http:// www. lectron .de >

It's a workshop of disabled people, so you are doing even something good.